# How to check if current user is an admin in Flutter using Firestore and FirebaseAuth

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to check if my user is an admin and display a widget depending on that. My data is stored in Firestore such that there is a document in a 'users' collection with a user ID that contains an 'isAdmin' field. My current code looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
              builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
                if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final uid = futureSnapshot.data.uid;
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .document(uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
                    if (userSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    var userDocument = userSnapshot.data;
                    if (userDocument['isAdmin'] == true) {
                      return FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                      );
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

However, this code runs and gives me an error that my build function returned null. How can I check if my current user is an admin if that data is stored in Firestore

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
              builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
                if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final uid = futureSnapshot.data.uid;
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .document(uid)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
                    if (userSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    var userDocument = userSnapshot.data.data();
                    if (userDocument['isAdmin'] == true) {
                      return FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                      );
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Change 'var userDocument = userSnapshot.data;'  to var userDocument = userSnapshot.data.data();

Comment: This gives me an error of The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#9a9a7):
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:3
Tried calling: call()